# Use of RRC(Range Rate Control) in Pseudo Range Correction for satellite

Tags: gps, rinex

Can anyone tell me the use of RRC in order to calculate the value of PRC(pseudo range correction) in PPK(post processed kinematics)?

[image: DGPS correction for Code Ranges]

[image: continue]

[image: continue]